# Python installation in Windows 10

Tags: python, installation

I tried to install Python 3.7.6 in windows 10. All went well until when in the cmd prompt of the computer as soon as I entered python to check the cmd prompt took me to microsoft app store and asked me to download python 3.7.7. It is not recognizing the python 3.7.6 that I had downloaded. Can any one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

it's just a case, i encountered the similar problem just download the app to get rid of the redirect to the store and it will be all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i have experienced the same issue .
But i have found an alternative solution to this problem.
Download Anaconda and then type "conda install python 3.7.6" in the anaconda prompt or u can also create a custom environment by typing "conda create -n py376 python=3.7.6 anaconda" in the anaconda prompt and then u shall see the version of python installed on ur environment by typing "python --version"